# Correct the goal of movebase

Tags: navigation, move-base, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a question about the goal correction of movebase.
Here are the pictures to explain my problem. [Pictures](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2G96eBtBMaMSWRmOVFxbTliUFU?usp=sharing)

In the 1.png, I choose a place as a goal and want my robot guide to the place.
The SLAM publishs TF (/map to /odom) while my robot is moving, so it cause the result as 2.png; my goal is different from my original one.

Is there any method to correct my goal to the original one while the SLAM publish the TF?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245106/correct-the-goal-of-movebase/) by [NickPig](https://answers.ros.org/users/28168/nickpig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be nice to know which SLAM algorithm you are using.

But no, this cannot be done easily.
Basically, the loop closure changes the map to be more consistent. But, the goal stays at the place it is with respect to the `map` coordinate frame.

What you would need to do is to somehow find the point in the map the goal is, then, in the SLAM algorithm, detect where this point is shifted to during the loop closure, and send this out as the new goal.

But this seems to be not trivial to implement, and you would need to change the SLAM algorithm, not `move_base`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NickPig](https://answers.ros.org/users/28168/nickpig/) on 2016-10-06**:
I see, thanks for the hint, I might detect the loop closure and resend the goal again. Thanks.